# Where are the official sources for libzbar?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management, libraries

`zbar` is a project that provides a barcode/qr-code scanning library and command line programs. `libzbar0` is provided in version `0.22` on Debian buster (our Docker images) and in version `0.23` on Ubuntu 20.04 (GitHub actions; same on Fedora 33 btw.). Our documents scan well with version `0.22` but don't with `0.23` and I wanted to report a bug. The only thing that looks like an official webpage (http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) seems to be really out of date, though, and only provides version `0.10` (and talks about really out of date Linux distributions).

Anyone know what the official website (or git reop) of that library is? Where do these newer versions come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is it:

https://github.com/mchehab/zbar

Saw in the README file from Debian packages

Answer (score 2):

The Debian web site tells you the project homepage. Look up the [package of interest](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libzbar0) and it's in the sidebar. Now you have found its github repo with a most recent commit two days ago.

Comment: Oh I totally missed that. (I was on that Debian page!)